# How to skip last row in the SSIS data flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, dataflow

I am using `FlatFile Source Manager` --> `Script COmponent as Trans` --> `OLEDB destination` in my data flow.

Source reads all the rows from flat file and i want to skip the last row (Trailer record) updating the database.

Since it contains the `NULL` values, database throws error.

Please assist me how to resolve this.

Regards,
VHK

Comment: This might can help you : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e51b775a-8601-491b-8ad4-a71b0f0d59ce/missing-last-row-when-package-is-run-as-a-job-from-sql-2008-r2?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to avoid rows having null values in the flat file then you can follow below approach,

- Read data from flat file using source component.
- Use `Conditional Split` component, and in the `case expression` provide as `!ISNULL(Column1) && !ISNULL(Column2)` (Column1 and Column2 can be as your wish. If your flat file has a column named, say `ID` and it does not have null value except the last row, then you can use as `!ISNULL(ID)`).
- Map the case output to the OLEDB destination.

Hope this would help you a lot.

Answer (score 6):

**To ignore the last row you have to do the following steps:**

1. Add a `DataFlow Task` *(let's name it `DFT RowCount`)*
2. Add a Global Variable of Type `System.Int32` *(Name: User::RowCount)*
3. In this DataFlow Task add a `Flat File Source` *(The file you want to import)*
4. Add a `RowCount` component next to the `Flat File Source`
5. Map the `RowCount` result to the variable `User::RowCount`

[image]

6. Add Another `DataFlow Task` *(let's name it `DFT Import`)*

[image]

7. In `DFT Import` add a `Flat File Source` *(File you need to Import)*
8. Add a `Script Component` next to the `Flat File Source`
9. Add `User::RowCount` Variable to the Script **ReadOnly Variables**

[image]

10. Add an Output Column of type `DT_BOOL` (Name: `IsLastRow`)

[image]

11. In the Script Window write the following Script

    ```
    Dim intRowCount As Integer = 0
    Dim intCurrentRow As Integer = 0
    Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
        MyBase.PreExecute()
        intRowCount = Variables.RowCount
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
        intCurrentRow += 1

        If intCurrentRow = intRowCount Then
            Row.IsLastRow = True
        Else
            Row.IsLastRow = False
        End If

    End Sub
    ```
12. Add a `Conditional Split` Next to the Script Component
13. Split Rows using the Following Expression

    ```
    [IsLastRow] == False
    ```

[image]

14. Add the `OLEDB Destination` next to the conditional Split

[image]

*Side Note: if you want to ignore rows for another case (not last row) just change the script writen in the script component to meet your requirements*